# Define Source one time and use it many times

Tags: wpf, xaml

Currently I am using the below code to Bind to the `TextBlock` to the `Application Settings`

```
<Grid DataSource="{Binding DataContext.CurrentPatient, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}">
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Test}" />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.CurrentValue}" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.NormalValue}" />
   ...
   ...
   ...
</Grid>
```

Now I don't want to type `Source={StaticResource Settings}` in all the textblocks.

In short I want Code-minification. I mean I want my code to be maintainable and reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Mybinding : Binding
{
    //Load only once and use every time :)
    static object Settings = App.Current.Resources["Settings"];

    public Mybinding()
    {
        Source = Settings; 
    }
}

 <TextBlock Text="{local:Mybinding Path=Default.Test}" />
```

**>Edit**

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
     <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

local is the namespace of Mybinding. I havent tested it .But hope this will give you an idea.And am Expecting "Settings" is in App.xaml or in ResourceDictionary Merged to App.xaml

Comment: I think your code will work well. I try it. But will it degrade the performance? I am asking this question because I have more than 1500 properties to be binded in my application.

Comment: keep this in some static variable of some global class and fill it once in beggining after App.xaml loaded and use it from there .yes if there are 1500 it will degrade the performance by looking for that property in Resource Dictionary every time.

Comment: you can have the Type of Property as your Settings type . but am sure object type will also work as binding uses reflection

Comment: Thanks. I will use it as you suggest.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mention your assumption that "Settings" is in App.xaml or ResourceDictionary merged with App.xaml. I am trying to follow http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx tutorial. There he has used `x:key="Settings"` but when I try to do the same thing I get an error that The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in an IDictionary.

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. Thanks for taking time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more grid and use its `DataContext`:

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}}>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Default.Test}" />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Default.CurrentValue}" />
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Default.NormalValue}" />
<Grid>
```